# MS Access or MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, database, web-services, ms-access

I have to create a website which has a data-base support.This is for my college project.I'm confused whether to use MS Access or Oracle MySQl to store the data-base...Which of these two has good compatibility and which is flexible.Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise You using MySQL(Windows) or MariaDB(Linux).

You may also try XAMPP(Windows) or LAMP(Linux) as it is good for a start.

Cheers.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the suggestion.Is there any website which has tutorial for connecting the HTML page with the database.

Comment: You may want to start with this site: [html.net tutorial](http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson20.php) but You will need to use PHP to access to database.